# Navigation Drawer on multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, responsive-design, navigation-drawer

I have a NavDrawer menu with a header_layouter.xml and a navigation_view_menu.xml. When it comes to the header_layout.xml, I simply can do multiple layouts but what a about the navigation_view_menu.xml?

My Question: How can I manage the NavDraw to match for all screen sizes?

My menu.xml

Thank you very  much in advance :)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group

    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    >

        <item

            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:title="@string/home"
            android:icon="@mipmap/home"
        />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/sponsor_1"
            android:title="@string/spons1"
            android:icon="@mipmap/video"
         />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/sponsor_2"
            android:title="@string/spons2"
            android:icon="@mipmap/video"
            />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/sponsor_3"
            android:title="@string/spons3"
            android:icon="@mipmap/video"
        />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/history"
            android:title="@string/NavHistory"
            android:icon="@mipmap/history"
        />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/Invite"
            android:title="@string/NavInvite"
            android:icon="@mipmap/share_nav"
        />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/Partner"
            android:title="@string/NavPartner"
            android:icon="@drawable/partner_icon_smaller_version"
            />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/Sign_out"
            android:title="@string/Sign_out"
            android:icon="@mipmap/sign_out"
        />

        <item

            android:id="@+id/About_us"
            android:title="@string/about_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/info"
            />

    </group>

</menu>
```